# Trouble with email validation

Tags: react-native

This time I have another issue when trying to deal with email validation. When I test my app, I fill the Email TextInput with a valid string, something like `Hello@email.com`, however, the `nonValidInput` bool stays at `null`, and subsequent attempts to post the Email adress don't work either, the `nonValidInput` bool now it's `true` when it must be `false` when entering a correct email adress.

The `_onSubmit` script is called when the button is pressed.

Here's my code:

```
state = { username: null, password: null, nonValidInput: null }

_validar = () => {
 let email = this.state.username
 let pattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

 if(pattern.test(String(email).toLowerCase) == true) {
   this.setState({ nonValidInput: false })
 } else {
   this.setState({ nonValidInput: true })
 }

  console.warn(this.state.nonValidInput)
}

_onSubmit = () =>{
 this._validar()

 if(this.state.nonValidInput == false) {
   const { username, password } = this.state;
 } else {
   this.setState({ nonValidInput: true })
 }
}
```

Again thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple of mistakes in your code.

1. `this.setState` is an async process. So call your `console.warn()` as a callback function.

```
if (pattern.test(String(this.state.username).toLowerCase()) == true) {
  this.setState({ nonValidInput: false }, () => console.warn("true"));
} else {
  this.setState({ nonValidInput: true }, () => console.warn("false"));
}
```

and make `_onSubmit` function as async until it process `_validar` function.

```
_onSubmit = async () => {
  await this._validar();
  if (this.state.nonValidInput == false) {
    const { username, password } = this.state;
  } else {
    this.setState({ nonValidInput: true });
  }
};
```

2. `toLowerCase` is a method, you can't call it as,

```
pattern.test(String(email).toLowerCase)
```

Change it to

```
pattern.test(String(email).toLowerCase())
```

Finally i see you are duplicating your code. In order to make your code clean add your validation part inside `submit`.

```
_onSubmit = () => {
  let pattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  if (pattern.test(String(this.state.username).toLowerCase()) == true) {
    this.setState({ nonValidInput: false });
    // you can call submit
  } else {
    this.setState({ nonValidInput: true });
    // you can handle error
  }
};
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it worked flawlessly!